# python in powershell vs python CLI

Tags: python, powershell

I am new to python, and I would like to ask what is the difference if I run python on Windows power-shell compared to when I run it directly and lunch the app's command-line?

Is there an impact if i use the latter method?

Answer (score 1):

Launching the "Python" application for the terminal interface seems to use the system's default command prompt, which, for Windows, is cmd.exe. If you run it this way, using `quit()` or `exit()` will exit the interpreter and then close the window entirely. If you start Python from an actual cmd window by running cmd and then running `py` or `python`, using `quit()` or `exit()` will exit the interpreter and leave you at the system's command line. Starting the interpreter from PowerShell with the `py` or `python` command means that you can use PowerShell's interface, which includes conveniences such as highlighting and right-clicking to copy and paste.

In terms of running Python code, there is no difference.